# BigDecimal java - precision bigger then provided value - how to fill with zeros

Tags: bigdecimal

I would like to control the exact value of a `BigDecimal`. with:

```
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(2.503);
```

I got

```
2.5030069968686868...
```

how to set up this overflow scale numbers to `0`?

I want to get:

```
2.503000000000000..0
```

I was trying with `setScale` without positive results.

Comment: what exactly you need? I have deleted the answer till I understand so I can edit my answer.

Comment: no it is not working. I need to get exact number ends with zeros. I think problem in putting double value into contractor of BigDecimal. Only string is giving proper number.